# Does the gauge transformation rule on the gauge fields satisfy the definition of group action?

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, lie-algebra, gauge-invariance

According to [definition group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action), it is required that action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ must satisfy the compatibility condition:
\begin{equation}
g \cdot (h \cdot x) = (gh) \cdot x \text{ for any } g,h \in G \text{ and} x \in X.
\end{equation}

Now, let $G$ be a typical gauge group such as $SU(2)$ or $SU(3)$ and $\lambda^j_{kl}$ be the structure constant of its Lie algebra.

Then, according to formula (1.72) in p.9 of "Gauge Field Theories 3rd edition" (2008) by Frampton, the gauge transformation rule of the gauge field $A$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\lambda^j_{kl} [g \cdot A]^{j}_\mu = g_{km} \lambda^j_{mn} A^j_{\mu} (g^{-1})_{nl} - i (\partial_{\mu} g_{km}) (g^{-1})_{ml}
\end{equation}
for any (smooth) $g : \mathbb{R}^4 \to G$. This seems called the adjoint action of $G$.

Now, my guestion is that, does this transformation satisfy the compatibility condition mentioned above? That is, for any $g,h : \mathbb{R}^4 \to G$, do we have
\begin{equation}
g \cdot [h \cdot A] = [gh] \cdot A?
\end{equation}

The additional term $ i (\partial_u g_{km}) (g^{-1})_{ml}$ appearing in the adjoint action seems to violate this requirement. Could anyone please clarify for me?

Comment: Where is the supposed violation? Can you write it down explicitly? Note that $\mathrm{d}(gh) (gh)^{-1} = \mathrm{d}g h h^{-1} g^{-1} + g\mathrm{d}h h^{-1} g^{-1} = \mathrm{d}g g^{-1} + + g\mathrm{d}h h^{-1} g^{-1} $

Comment: @ACuriousMind I can't see why $g dhh^{-1}g^{-1}$ fits into the formula of the action $g \cdot [h \cdot A]$.

Comment: It's just plugging in the definitions, no? $g\cdot [h\cdot A] = g\cdot [ hAh^{-1} + \mathrm{d}h h^{-1}] = g ( hAh^{-1} + \mathrm{d}h h^{-1}) g^{-1} + \mathrm{d}g g^{-1}$